# Javascript Loop Back To Start Of Array When Index Is Larger Than Array Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexing

I have been looking everywhere for a solution for this but I cant seem to find an answer anywhere! Maybe I'm just wording my question wrong, but how can I loop back to the start of an array if the index is larger than the array length? See my code below for an example:

```
// Array of colours
let colours = ["#FFBE36", "#FF6447", "#77FF47", "#D547FF", "#FF9E47", "#47DBFF", "#FF4770"];

// For each pack, a background colour from the array above is assigned. 
// However, these are fetched from a database so could be more than the 
// length of the array
var packs = document.getElementsByClassName("pack-item");
for (var i = 0, len = packs.length; i < len; i++) {
    // Here if i is larger than colours.length, loop back to start of 
    // colours array, e.g colours[8] = "#FFBE36"
    packs[i].style.backgroundColor = colours[i];
}
```

I hope this makes sense? Let me know if you want me to word it differently/explain in more detail!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with the modulo operator ( % ) like below. That would allow the counter to stay the correct length and the colors would stay in order.

```
// Array of colours
let colours = ["#FFBE36", "#FF6447", "#77FF47", "#D547FF", "#FF9E47", "#47DBFF", "#FF4770"];

// For each pack, a background colour from the array above is assigned. 
// However, these are fetched from a database so could be more than the 
// length of the array
var packs = document.getElementsByClassName("pack-item");
for (var i = 0, len = packs.length; i < len; i++) {
    // Here if i is larger than colours.length, loop back to start of 
    // colours array 
    packs[i].style.backgroundColor = colours[i % colours.length];
}
```

Comment: @Samathingamajig this is probably the correct answer.  Assuming the user does not want an infinite loop and simply wants to handle for the case that say, there are 21 packs, and they only have 7 colors, this logic would assign a color to each pack, looping the colors when it reaches the end of the colors array.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to do with a `while` loop so you have the `colorPointer` that you increment and if it is equal to the `colors.length-1` which is the true length of the array since it is zero indexed it will go back to the beginning.

```js
// Array of colours
let colours = ["#FFBE36", "#FF6447", "#77FF47", "#D547FF", "#FF9E47", "#47DBFF", "#FF4770"];

// For each pack, a background colour from the array above is assigned. 
// However, these are fetched from a database so could be more than the 
// length of the array
let counter = 0;
let colorPointer = 0;
var packs = document.getElementsByClassName("pack-item");
while(counter < packs.length) {
  // Here if i is larger than colours.length, loop back to start of 
    // colours array 
    packs[counter].style.backgroundColor = colours[colorPointer];
    counter++;
    colorPointer++;
    if(colorPointer === colours.length-1){
      colorPointer = 0;
    }
}
```